# R data structure encoded with meta data

Tags: r, structure, metadata

I've got a data structure as shown below:

[image: R data structure with meta data]

It seems to be a data frame with meta data. I was able to manually build the data frame for this example with

```
d = data.frame(a1=x$value$value[1], a2=x$value$value[2], a3=x$value$value[3])
a=x$attributes
colnames(d)=a$names$value
```

However, I wonder if this is some sort of standard exchange format and if there is a more general solution to read the embedded data into a variable?

**EDIT**

The data structure came from an RDX2 file which contains JSON

```
load("data.json")
x=fromJSON(data_json)
```

The JSON structure contains the same data:

[image: JSON data]

Comment: Try `data.frame(x$value$value)`

Comment: @akrun this is shorter but doesn't set the column names

Comment: You need custom names, so use `setNames` i.e. `setNames(data.frame(x$value$value), paste0("a", 1:3)))`

Comment: @akrun ok, this is the one liner `setNames(data.frame(x$value$value), a$names$value)`, thanks. However it still seems to be a generic format for which I expect some library function.

Comment: Have you checked out the `labelled` package for these kind of meta data often found in spss/ stata/sas files <https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/labelled/vignettes/intro_labelled.html>

Comment: @MDEWITT I added some information about how the data came into. I tried the package but without knowing which application has exported the data this is cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: the above is the result of serializing a data frame with

```
rlist::serialize(data, "data.json")
```

to a json file. Afterwards this file has been read as plain text, the text is converted using `rjson::fromJSON`, and the R data structure is written as it is to another file. Instead of this

```
data = rlist::unserialize("data.json")
```

should have been used.